# Docker for Windows - container domain name cannot be resolved

Tags: windows, docker, dns

I want to set up developer environment on local machine with `docker-compose`. And I'm trying to assign some predefined domain names for my sites. It must be a three level domain like *app1.myapps.test*, instead of just *app1*.

I want Docker to assign these host names automatically using two properties *hostname* and *domainname*, instead of assigning static IPs to containers and adding these IPs to `hosts` file manually.

My Docker compose file is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app1:
    build: .
    container_name: app-1
    domainname: myapps.test
    hostname: app1
```

Trying to open http://app1.myapps.test/ and see error telling me that DNS address could not be resolved.
If I remove property `domainname: myapps.test` then it works fine and I'm able to access my site by hostname http://app1/.

Changing settings to (without domainname)

```
hostname: app1.myapps.test
```

or to

```
domainname: myapps.test
hostname: app1.myapps.test
```

didn't help as well.

Is there a way for Docker DNS to set multi-level domains and how option `domainname` works? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you missed something but because of duplicate names in your compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  app1:
    build: .
    container_name: app-1
    domainname: myapps.test
    hostname: app1
```

If you change it to below

```
version: '3'
services:
  app1:
    build: .
    container_name: app-1
```

It should still work. When you say

> I'm able to access my site by hostname http://app1/.

That is because it is the name of the service. Not because you specified `hostname: app1`. So what you really need is network aliases. And since you are using the default network. You can use something like below

```
version: '3'
services:
  app1:
    build: .
    container_name: app-1
    hostname: app1
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - app1.myapps.test
```